# Is there a Hook or Signal in TYPO3 core for executing code before rendering?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I need to check something before the rendering process is starting to handle a possible redirect fast.
Where can I find a hook or signal which I can use to use my code before the rendering starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['tslib/index_ts.php']['preprocessRequest']` hook for this.

With TYPO3v9 you can register your own middleware instead and have it executed early. (In fact that hook is a middleware in TYPO3v9.)